# How to deal with non-normal heterocedastic data from a factorial experiment?

Tags: anova, nonparametric, interaction, heteroscedasticity, post-hoc

I ran an experiment with two factors each with two levels, 5 replicates each combination and one response variable. My data are non-normal and heterocedastic. Transformations didn't help. I ran a permutation ANOVA (`aovp - package lmperm - R`), but I am not sure this is the right way to go and I don't know what to do about a post hoc test, because I have a significant interaction. This is what my data look like:

```
F1 F2 BIOMASS
A C 0.66
A C 0.31
A C 0.88
A C 0.55
A C 0.81
A D 0.39
A D 0.21
A D 0.17
A D 0.15
A D 0.18
B C 0.00
B C 0.18
B C 0.05
B C 0.00
B C 0.02
B D 0.16
B D 0.04
B D 0.21
B D 0.15
B D 0.06
```

Comment: What is your response variable? Is it a continuous variable that just happens to fall between 0 & 1? Is it the proportion of successes from some number of Bernoulli trials? Is it a continuous proportion?

Comment: Your permutation test will assume equal distributions under the null. If you're after a location-shift alternative that won't be suitable (but it might work for a scale-shift). My first instinct would be to consider something like a GLM but it partly depends on what your response is.

Answer (score 1):

*Your response variable is suspicious.  If it is a continuous proportion, you may want to pursue beta regression (I have an example of a BR in* `R` *here: [Remove effect of factor on continuous proportion data using regression in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94766/7290).  If it is the outcome of some number of Bernoulli trials (and you know the number), you should disaggregate and use logistic regression (or use a weighted LR).  The following assumes the data are simply from a continuous variable, and happen to be within the (0, 1) interval.*

I think most of this may be covered by my answer here: [Alternatives to one-way ANOVA for heteroscedastic data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/91881/7290).  In general, permutation tests are not recommended when you have heteroscedasticity.  In your case, I might suggest using ordinal logistic regression.  Since you have a 2x2, the post-hoc tests are just two 2-group comparisons, which could be done by repeating the original analysis on the stratified data.  Under the assumption that the global test of the initial model is significant, I wouldn't even worry about multiple comparisons.

Comment: My response variable is plant biomass... it just happened to be between 0 and 1. I took a look at the alternatives to one-way ANOVA, but I have two factors to analyse. I also checked the ordinal logistic regression but I don't think it makes sense for my data. I'll keep searching. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I recognize that that question was about one-way ANOVA & you have a two-way ANOVA, but most of the methods will generalize to >1 factor. OLR is the most general non-parametric approach. All you need is for your data to be ordinal in nature, ie you need to be able to confidently say .66>.31, if you can say that, you can use OLR.